# How can use CustomerData to store custom value in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

i want use CustomerData to store image & content on browser storage in magento 2.

I try to follow tutorial but  not get success yet
https://aionhill.com/magento-2-module-development-guide-part-4-knockout-js

Answer (score 3):

Have you been able to store anything?

https://digita.lism.ro/2017/09/magento-2-using-customerdata-populate-block-asynchronously/

app/code/Vendor/Module/CustomerData/Example.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

/**
 * Example data source
 */
class Example extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject implements SectionSourceInterface
{
    public function getSectionData() {

        return [
            'active' => 'This is active'
        ];
    }
}
```

The return array is simply an example, you can return any information you need to pass to the block.

You will then need to declare it in your module’s

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="example" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\CustomerData\Example</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

In order to control when this information will be requested and updated (Magento makes multiple ajax request per page and can update your CustomerData multiple times if necessary) we need to add some information to our module’s

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/sections.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="example/action/*">
        <section name="example"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Corresponding with the routes your customer data depends on, you can add the actions to request your example section to be updated.

Now that we have the customer data set up, we will need to call it in a block using a javascript component.

Add your block to the layout where you need it, let’s say we want to add it to the header panel (add your block to the app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml file in your module)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::example.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now in your module create

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/example.phtml

```
<div id="example-header">
    <span data-bind="text: example().active"></span>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example": {
                    "component": "Vendor_Example/js/example"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This adds the js component example (which we will create right now) to your block and will bind the span’s value with the one we will pass to it.

Create app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/example.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this.example = customerData.get('example');
                this._super();
            },
        });
    }
);
```

Your block should now be dynamically updated with the value from the customerData object , by using the example customerData response you have defined

Comment: How can I check Browser

Comment: console.log(this.example)  or it will appear in phtml. Look at example-header

Comment: ReferenceError: example is not defined

Comment: knockout.js:3391 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return example().active }"
Message: example is not defined (Chrome)

Comment: I am unable to get this to work. Specifically, I'm not able to get the custom customer data. The initialize function is being called (console.log is being triggered) but my data is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Previous post is correct, except file example.phtml,
should be used scope

```
<div id="example-header" data-bind="scope: 'example'">
<span data-bind="text: example().active"></span></div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example": {
                    "component": "Vendor_Example/js/example"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```